# Change the level of boldness of font in ms-word

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

How do I modify the level of boldness for text in MS-OFFICE 2016? I am unable to change it from what's default when we click bold. We have three default options of font including bold, italic and underline. When I select bold it gets a certain degree of weight to the font. I want to control the level of boldness or the weight on it. Basically, for a given font style, say times new roman, I want different part of the text to look differently bold, with different widths of the letter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Bold" (B button) of a normal font in Word is set by the program and the default properties do not change.

In general, you can download and use other fonts (as already mentioned by DrMoishe)

In addition, you can also try "text effects and typography":

[image]